# Akka HTTP Ajax call with parameters

Tags: ajax, scala, akka-http

I am working with a use case where I need to make a call to Azkaban via AJAX APi provided by Azkaban which is like

```
curl -k -X POST --data "session.id=9089beb2-576d-47e3-b040-86dbdc7f523e&name=aaaa&description=11" https://localhost:8443/manager?action=create
```

Now how using akka HTTP rest services can I send a payload with `--data` parameter
ie `--data "session.id=9089beb2-576d-47e3-b040-86dbdc7f523e&name=aaaa&description=11"` part

> I tried using RequestBuilding
>
> ```
>    object AzkabanTest extends App{
>       implicit val system = ActorSystem()
>       implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
>       implicit val executor: ExecutionContext = system.dispatcher
>
>       val payloadObject ="action=login&username=amdin&password=admin"
>       val url = "https://127.0.0.1:8443"
>       val request = Post(url, payloadObject)
>       val result: Future[HttpResponse] = Http()
>         .singleRequest(request)
>
>       def extract(responseFuture: Future[HttpResponse]): HttpResponse = Await.result(responseFuture, 10.seconds)
>
>       val res = extract(result).entity.toString
>       println(res)   
>     }
> The Result should be JsonObject but 
>     {
>       "session.id" : "ee39c901-eac9-48cd-9b3a-b25c00e8bde2",
>       "status" : "success"
>     }
> ```
>
> its generating empty List()

Error

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1431)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:535)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.writeAppRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1214)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.wrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:1186)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.wrap(SSLEngine.java:469)
    at akka.stream.impl.io.TLSActor.akka$stream$impl$io$TLSActor$$doWrap(TLSActor.scala:348)
    at akka.stream.impl.io.TLSActor.akka$stream$impl$io$TLSActor$$doOutbound(TLSActor.scala:317)
    at akka.stream.impl.io.TLSActor$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(TLSActor.scala:228)
    at akka.stream.impl.Pump$class.pump(Transfer.scala:199)
    at akka.stream.impl.io.TLSActor.pump(TLSActor.scala:48)
    at akka.stream.impl.BatchingInputBuffer.enqueueInputElement(ActorProcessor.scala:90)
    at akka.stream.impl.BatchingInputBuffer$$anonfun$upstreamRunning$1.applyOrElse(ActorProcessor.scala:141)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
    at akka.stream.impl.SubReceive.apply(Transfer.scala:16)
    at akka.stream.impl.FanIn$InputBunch$$anonfun$subreceive$1.applyOrElse(FanIn.scala:234)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
    at akka.stream.impl.SubReceive.apply(Transfer.scala:16)
    at akka.stream.impl.SubReceive.apply(Transfer.scala:12)
    at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
    at akka.stream.impl.SubReceive.applyOrElse(Transfer.scala:12)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:170)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:484)
    at akka.stream.impl.io.TLSActor.aroundReceive(TLSActor.scala:48)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1728)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:304)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1509)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:919)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:916)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1369)
    at akka.stream.impl.io.TLSActor.runDelegatedTasks(TLSActor.scala:402)
    at akka.stream.impl.io.TLSActor.akka$stream$impl$io$TLSActor$$doUnwrap(TLSActor.scala:371)
    at akka.stream.impl.io.TLSActor.akka$stream$impl$io$TLSActor$$doInbound(TLSActor.scala:290)
    at akka.stream.impl.io.TLSActor$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(TLSActor.scala:225)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchIP(HostnameChecker.java:144)
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:93)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:455)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:436)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:252)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:136)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1496)
    ... 34 more
```

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to send single request only you should use [Request-Level Client-Side API](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/client-side/request-level.html) with [`Post`](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/blob/master/akka-http/src/main/scala/akka/http/scaladsl/client/RequestBuilding.scala#L56) request:

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.client.RequestBuilding._

val request = Post(url, payloadObject)

val result: Future[YourTargetResult] = Http()
  .singleRequest(request)
  .flatMap(handleResponse)

def handleResponse(response: HttpResponse): YourTargetResult = ...
```

`payloadObject` should be serializable according to the format of choice. In your particular case you might want to make it just a string with desired payload. In more sophisticated cases where XML/JSON is needed you'll need to provide marshallers into desired format (i.e. Spray JSON).

*UPD*: According to curl [man page](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html), in order to build a payload similar to what curl would have for multiple `--data` parameters, just concatenate the values with `&`:

> -d, --data
>
> If any of these options is used more than once on the same command line, the data pieces specified will be merged together with a separating &-symbol. Thus, using '-d name=daniel -d skill=lousy' would generate a post chunk that looks like 'name=daniel&skill=lousy'.

Comment: I have payload in string format only 
`curl -k --get --data 'session.id=189b956b-f39f-421e-9a95-e3117e7543c9' --data 'ajax=executeFlow' --data 'project=azkaban-test-project' --data 'flow=test' https://localhost:8443/executor` 
What I need to know is how to pass it to paramater `--data` just as for fileUpload we have `--form` mentioned here https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.0.10/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/file-upload-directives/fileUpload.html#fileupload

Comment: @Freeman have you tried what I suggested? I believe if you just pass a string value as `payloadObject` it will end up in POST payload, just as `--data` flag does. Regarding multiple --data flags - see update in the answer.

Comment: I have updated the problem with solution suggested by you , still not getting what is expected .can you please have a look

Comment: @Freeman I haven't had to deal with HTTPS from akka-http yet, so unfortunately I can't provide any further insight except suggesting to consult with docs: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/client-side/client-https-support.html